# A gravitational field is path independent. Why does a rocket not fly in serpentine lines?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, reference-frames, rocket-science, conservative-field

in theory a gravitational field is *path independent*, a gravitational field is a *gradient field* and so *conservative*. why doesn't a rocket fly in serpentine lines to exit the gravitational field of the moon, as said the gravitational field of the moon is path independent and the moon has no atmosphere and so there is no aerodynamic drag?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_theorem

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field#Path_independence

i know that the reason is that flying in serpentine lines would require more energy ( fuel ) however *where is this surplus of energy for a serpentine line path reflected in the theories*?

Comment: A serpentine path requires constantly going against the inertia of the rocket (its momentum), and this costs energy. A better path has smoother variations of momentum.

Comment: For the practical aspect, you may want to ask over at [space.se].

Answer (score 2):

I sometimes walk up broad stairs or slopes in a serpentine or diagonal way; the change in potential *energy* is the same, but the *power* needed is smaller. In many physics cases there is a limit on how much power can be supplied.

A rocket works by ejecting reaction mass to generate thrust: $$m\frac{dv}{dt}=-v_e \frac{dm}{dt} + F.$$ Note that without force $F$ this equation "doesn't care" when you fire your engine, the overall effect is the same increment of velocity - but if you care how fast you get to a particular point you want the high speed to show up early so most of the distance is covered at high speed.

While the force $F$ may be conservative for constant mass-objects, this may not be true for changing mass objects. If $F=GMm/r^2$ the force later can be reduced if you expel a lot of mass early when $r$ is small. Conversely, if you want to make a velocity change there is a $\Delta v/\dot{m}$ advantage in doing that when you are close to a planet (an Oberth manoeuvre). So in a sense there is a lot of "snaking around" when deciding when to fire the engines.

However, the question was about general travel from A to B. Note that if you fire your engine a bit sideways rather than steering "straight" at B then you will eventually have to fire it again to get an opposing sideways velocity so you don't miss B. That is wasted energy: you both had to spend energy to cancel the earlier firing, and you have less energy to bring you to your destination fast.

Comment: yes, and now this has to be transfered to path integrals, because in theory of gradient fields / conservative fields ( or resp a gravitational field ) there is *path independence*, although in reality the *path matters* ( more energy required and longer time of flight ). very likely the answer is related to the fact that power is linked to time $t$  ( $P = \frac{E}{t}$ ) and time is not a variable in gradient fields that are defined purely spatial. so in a sense spatial gradient fields are defined as invariant under time or time independent...

Comment: Simply put, you are considering only the gravitational force on the rocket, there are many others including air drag. The rocket follows the path of TOTAL least resistance. This is much more obvious in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics

Answer (score 1):

What you say would be true if rockets were held up by, say, a very long string. Since real rockets don’t have such a string available they have to do something much less efficient: fight the gravitational force by pushing fuel downward. A rocket needs to exert energy just to stay in the same place, let alone move in a fancy pattern! This is why a space elevator would be so helpful; it’s essentially just a long string extending out to space.

Comment: yes, but this is not reflected in the theory. a fancy path requires more energy and so there is a difference between a straight path and a serpentine path. in theory this difference is discarded and both paths are declared to be equal meaning that the quantity *energy* is not observed in the theory. i want to know why this difference in energy is discarded in theory ...

Comment: @ralfhtp The theory only says that the integral of $\mathbf{F} \cdot d \mathbf{x}$ is independent of path. If you implement the force in a good way (i.e. by a dangling string), that means the energy needed is in principle independent of path. If you implement the force in a "bad" way, such as a rocket, then you can require much more energy.

Comment: @ralfhtp I can just turn on my car's engine and let it idle for a few hours. It will cost energy even though $\int \mathbf{F} \cdot d \mathbf{x}$ is zero, but that does not mean the work-kinetic energy theorem is wrong. The theory is not responsible for knowing all the other ways one could waste energy (in this case, turning chemical energy into thermal energy), it's just about kinetic energy.

Comment: no, on a dangling string the forces at its 'bearing' are different for a straight or a serpentine path and also the time that the forces on the 'bearing' are active. i think the solution is that gradient fields are commonly defined purely *spatial* and that *time* $t$ is therefore excluded from observation. i added this in the comment under @Anders Sandbergs answer. it is the same with  the car engine. to let it run '*for a few hours*' is the *temporal relation* that is excluded from observation in purely *spatial* theory of gradient fields ...

Comment: @ralfhtp You're free to invent another quantity, besides work, that takes time into account. We don't do this in physics because the right quantity will depend on all the details -- it'll be different for a rocket and a car and a string. We leave these details to the engineers.

Comment: deleted last comment because i thought about it and i do not know if it was accurate. the concept of power is linked to time $t$ as $P = \frac{E}{t} = \frac{W}{t}$ however it implies that the longer a mass point remains in the gradient field the less power it requires what is obviously inaccurate for a rocket...

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose that instead of traveling straight up, the rocket travels some distance north (and up), and then changes its direction and flies south (and up), ending up at the same elevation as in the original flight plan.  Your question is, "why does the second flight plan require more energy, since the change in the rocket's gravitational potential energy is the same in both cases"?

The answer is that to change direction, the rocket also requires an expenditure of fuel.  This comes not from energy conservation but from momentum conservation:  to change velocity from northward to southward, the rocket must eject a significant amount of mass (fuel) at high speed northward.  This ejected fuel will have a significant amount of kinetic energy due to its horizontal motion;  and this energy is effectively "wasted", since it doesn't contribute to the upward motion of the rocket.  In other words, what is conserved (roughly) is the following:
$$
(\text{chemical energy of initial fuel}) = (\text{final KE of rocket}) + (\text{final PE of rocket}) \\+ (\text{final KE of ejected fuel}) + (\text{final PE of ejected fuel})
$$
If you are giving the fuel additional kinetic energy in the horizontal direction while trying to keep the final KE and PE of the rocket the same, you'll need more initial fuel to do this.  (And then the [tyranny of the rocket equation](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/expeditions/expedition30/tryanny.html) kicks in.)

Comment: energy conservation is linked to time ( time-energy uncertainty ) and momentum conservation is   linked to space ( space-momentum uncertainty )  a rocket that changes direction or a rocket in horizontal motion does not only require a surplus  of fuel but also a surplus time.  in the gradient field formalism the quantity time is not in the picture at all it is simply discarded, the gradient field formalism is invariant under time ...

Answer (score 0):

> In theory a gravitational field is path independent, a gravitational field is a gradient field and so conservative.

Correct.  But what this means is that the total work done *by gravity* is constant over the path.

> why doesn't a rocket fly in serpentine lines to exit the gravitational field of the moon, as said the gravitational field of the moon is path independent and the moon has no atmosphere and so there is no aerodynamic drag?

Because the rocket is using its engines.  And the engines are *not* a conservative force on the rocket.  The work done by the engines on the rocket depend on the speed and direction of the rocket.

Comment: work is not dependent on speed, work is defined as $W = F \cdot s$ where $F$ is force and $s$ is path, so time $t$ is not in the picture ( $\vec v = \frac{ \vec s}{t}$ ), however it is dependent on direction $\vec{s}$. Also  see my comment under @Michael Seifert s answer